Eachine ts215 motors get hot
I bought a Eachine Wizard TS215 5' freestyle drone back in 2020 (now discontinued) that flew perfectly when I bought it. The PID tunning was already set from the factory and everything was running nicely.
I broke one the arms in 2022, ordered a new one and some new props, but didn't fly again until 2024. I stored the drone inside it's box and there was no signs of humidity or corrosion when I got it out.
Now, in 2024, all my motors are extremely hot just by hovering and my batteries get drained super quickly even though in beta flight I can get around 15amps draw.
I checked for shortages between the motor and the frame but didn't find any. It's worth noting that I replaced the props for a lower pitch 5' props but should be okay for my 2450kv motors. I didn't touch the PID tunning since but I've tried reducing the D factor to 5 to see if it would stop them from overheating (it didn't).
One of the motors is vibrating more then the others causing my drone to twitch a bit (still flyable though) but this motor has never damaged.
I also have a slight crack on one of the arms
I've been searching the internet for answer didn't find anything.
Any ideas as to why my motors would be running hot?
Could there be rust inside the motor for being put away for 2 years?
